# Elasticsearch 'failed to find filter under name '

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I'am just started with ES 5.2.2
Trying ad analyzer with support russian morhology.
Run ES using docker, i create image with installed elasticsearch-analysis-morphology.
then i:
Create index, 
then put settings

after that get settings, and all sems right

```
curl http://localhost:9200/news/_settings?pretty
{
"news" : {
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "number_of_shards" : "5",
    "provided_name" : "news",
    "creation_date" : "1489343955314",
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "russian_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "stop",
            "custom_stop",
            "russian_stop",
            "custom_word_delimiter",
            "lowercase",
            "russian_morphology",
            "english_morphology"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "html_strip",
            "ru"
          ],
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }
      },
      "char_filter" : {
        "ru" : {
          "type" : "mapping",
          "mappings" : [
            "Ё=>Е",
            "ё=>е"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter:" : {
        "custom_stop" : {
          "type" : "stop",
          "stopwords" : [
            "n",
            "r"
          ]
        },
        "russian_stop" : {
          "ignore_case" : "true",
          "type" : "stop",
          "stopwords" : [
            "а",
            "без",
          ]
        },
        "custom_word_delimiter" : {
          "split_on_numerics" : "false",
          "generate_word_parts" : "false",
          "preserve_original" : "true",
          "catenate_words" : "true",
          "generate_number_parts" : "true",
          "catenate_all" : "true",
          "split_on_case_change" : "false",
          "type" : "word_delimiter",
          "catenate_numbers" : "false"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "uuid" : "IUkHHwWrStqDMG6fYOqyqQ",
    "version" : {
      "created" : "5020299"
    }
  }
 }
}
}
```

then i try open index but ES give me this:

```
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to verify index [news/IUkHHwWrStqDMG6fYOqyqQ]"
  }
],
"type" : "exception",
"reason" : "Failed to verify index [news/IUkHHwWrStqDMG6fYOqyqQ]",
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason" : "Custom Analyzer [russian_analyzer] failed to find filter         under name [custom_stop]"
}
},
"status" : 500
}
```

Can't understand where i'm wrong. 
Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: What is the query you send to your Elastic node?

Comment: @asettouf curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/news/_open/?pretty'

Comment: @asettouf I have filling that my settings have wrong syntax

Comment: That is one of the strangest thing I have ever seen, if I make a test with your config to create an index (copy pasting), I get the same error, if I rewrite it and it is completely equivalent, the index is created succesfully. The only thing I can see of right now is that somehow the encoding is wrongly interpreted... Also elastic in debug mode does not show anything more helpful...

Comment: @asettouf o_O veeery strange... Thank you. I'll try to rewrite it.

Comment: @asettouf there was mistake "filter:"  two dots in the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was mistake in "filter" section

```
 was:

look here this This colon was a mistake
       |
       v
"filter:" : {
    "custom_stop" : {
      "type" : "stop",
      "stopwords" : [
        "n",
        "r"
      ]
    }...
```

Thanks @asettou and @andrey-morozov